# Getting an inner bundle from a bigger bundle in Android

Tags: android, bundle

I have a function in my Android code where I get a bundle as input:

```
void f(Bundle data)
```

This `data` is actually in the form of a json. Suppose it is in the following format:
`{"a":"x", "b":"y", "content":{"a1":"x1", "b1":"y1"}}`

In such cases, if I want to get the value of a, or b, then I would need to do `String a = data.getString("a");` which would fetch me the string `"x"`. Similarly, `String content = data.getString("content")` would return me the string `{"a1":"x1", "b1":"y1"}}`. But I cannot figure out how to get the specific values inside content itself. Is there any way by which I can get `content` as another bundle just like `data` so that I can get the values inside it by doing `content.getString("a1")` or something like that. Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you use JSONObject instead bundle?

Comment: something obvious like getBundle?  Did you at least read the Bundle docs?

Comment: Yes, and it returns null. Didn't work, hence asked. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use JSONObject instead of Bundle, because the arguments in the function are not in my control. If you know there's a solution assuming that I am receiving a Bundle alone, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject jOBj = new JSONobject(data.getString("content"));
String a1 = jOBj.getString("x1");
String b1 = jOBj.getString("y1");
```

try this

Comment: `data` is a Bundle. Bundle class does not have a `getJSONObject` function.

Comment: data.getString("content").getString("a1");

Comment: `data.getString("content")` returns a String.
So `data.getString("content").getString("a1");` makes no sense because String object does not have a `getString` function in the first place

Answer (score 0):

**To get value from bundle and create JSon object/ Hashmap**

```
private void createFlatJSon(Bundle appRestrictions,JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException{
    for (String key : appRestrictions.keySet()) {
        if (appRestrictions.get(key) instanceof Bundle) {
            createFlatJSon((Bundle) appRestrictions.get(key),jsonObject);
        }else if (appRestrictions.get(key) instanceof Parcelable[]){
            for (int i=0;i< ((Parcelable[]) appRestrictions.get(key)).length; i++){
                createFlatJSon((Bundle)((Parcelable[]) appRestrictions.get(key))[i],jsonObject);
            }
            //Log.e("KEY skipped",appRestrictions.get(key).toString());
        }else{

           Log.e("KEY: ",key+" Value:"+appRestrictions.get(key).toString());
            jsonObject.put(key,appRestrictions.get(key).toString());

        }
    }


}
```